# Bootstrap 4 change caret on clicking dropdown

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4, I am trying to create a dropdown with caret (Ex: pointing right). On clicking dropdown the caret pointing direction should be changed (Ex: down).

I have got a [way to do that](https://codepen.io/tofanelli/pen/waadRY)

```
/*Please refer the above link for full code details*/

<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
</a>

<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        This content is hidden
      </div>
</div>
```

**.css**

```
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e114";
    float: right;
    color: grey;
}
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
    content: "\e080";
}
```

**But the catch is, initially all the carets pointing down which should be right**

There are other [approaches](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_icon&stacked=h). But I don't want to use JQuery, as my application is angular 4. Would like to avoid JQuery/JS as much as possible.

This is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677222/bootstrap-dropdown-make-dropdown-arrow-change-direction) question.

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: When you initially create the accordions, by-default add a `collapsed` class to the anchor with class `accordion-toggle`. this would make them point right.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Bootstrap V4 they have dropped the **Glyphicons**. Below code will work well as per your need.
For drop-down icon style, you can use font awesome.

```css
[data-toggle="collapse"]:after {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  content: "\f054";
  transform: rotate(90deg) ;
  transition: all linear 0.25s;
  }   
[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed:after {
  transform: rotate(0deg) ;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="accordion" role="tablist">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [codepen demo link](https://codepen.io/satheesh_design/pen/rGxRBy)

Note: In your demo link they have used Bootstrap V3.

Comment: it worked for me. Thank you. You are true, its an example for Bootstrap3. In your example, caret is constructed. As you mentioned, it would be great to see an example with font awesome icons

Comment: Did you need an example with font awesome icon included?

Comment: Yes..bootstrap 4 with font awesome example. Just a button with toggle right.on clicking, caret pointing down and display  some text.would be very helpful..Thank you

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code as per your need, and also here I have attached the Codepen link. ( https://codepen.io/satheesh_design/pen/rGxRBy ) this will be useful for you thanks :)

Comment: Worked. Thank you. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154831/discussion-between-vinni-and-satheesh-kumar).

Comment: Remove the float:right and it will align vertical centre.

Comment: do you have a working example with bootstrap 4.1.0 and fontawesome 5.0.0?

Comment: @GoodJeans, you use the same structure for font awesome 5.0.0

Comment: Amazing example, thanks! For Bootstrap 5 users, remember to replace `data-toggle` with `data-bs-toggle`.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I [got this working](https://codepen.io/Vinnim/pen/veGgLV) with Bootstrap4-CSS-fontAwesome & No JS/JQuery.

```
<a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#anyId">
  click
</a>

<div id="anyId" class="collapse">
    Hi
</div>

<!-- CDNs for font-awesome, bootstrap, JQuery -->
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**.css**

```
.accordion-toggle:after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';/* essential to enable caret symbol*/
  content: "\f0d7";/* adjust as needed, taken from font-awesome.css */
  color: grey;
}
.accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
  /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
  content: "\f0da";  /* adjust as needed, taken from font-awesome.css */
}
```

Thank you @Satheesh Kumar

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got mine working using only CSS for bootstrap 4.2 and fontawesome. I've used the aria label and added transitions for the icon, using a span class for the icon

**CSS:**

```
#accordionExample .btn[aria-expanded=false] span:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f107";
  float: right;
 transition: all .5s;
}

#accordionExample .btn[aria-expanded=true] span:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f107";
  float: right;
  transition: all .5s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container my-5 mw-600">
  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">

        <a class="btn btn-link d-flex" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
          <span class="ml-auto"></span></a>

    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">

        <a class=" btn btn-link collapsed d-flex align-items-center" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
          <span class="ml-auto"></span>
        </a>

    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">

        <a class="btn btn-link collapsed d-flex" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false">
          Collapsible Group Item #3<span class="ml-auto"></span>
        </a>

    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XoLgbY

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SCSS, there are built-in mixins especially for this, located at `~bootstrap/scss/mixins/_caret.scss`.

`caret-down`, `caret-up`, `caret-right`, `caret-left` and `caret($direction)`.

So, this can become as easy as:

```
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle {
    @include caret(right);

    &.collapsed {
        @include caret(left);
    }
}
```

or, if your HTML contains `aria-expanded` attribute (which is highly advised)

```
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle {
    &[aria-expanded="false"] {
        @include caret(left);
    }

    &[aria-expanded="true"] {
        @include caret(right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more for non-css developer for aria-expanded code?

Comment: @ZinMin I've used [aria-expanded] attribute here just as a selector, because it's under Bootstrap's examples and it handles triggering that for you ([aria-expanded]="true|false"). There's no magic under it, it's just an attribute on HTML element. Check this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp if you're unfamiliar with CSS selectors. It always helps me :)

Answer (score 0):

I used Vinni's solution, it seemed to me the simplest one, but the icon showed as a box with Chrome and Firefox, only Safari and Chrome mobile displayed correctly, I did some digging and found out that the new version of Font Awesome also requires font-weight: 900; when you use solid icons in custom css classes, so while some icons may showed fine the caret I was using (f0d7) didn't and needed font-weight 900; I also used font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free'; instead of only font-family: 'FontAwesome'; The revised CSS looks like this:

```
.accordion-toggle:after {
font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
font-weight: 900;
content: "\f0d7";/
color: grey;
}
.accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
content: "\f0da";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one too. CSS Only.

```
.navbar-nav .dropdown.open .caret{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```