# How to add a collapse icon in ngx-bootstrap Accordion

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-accordion

In my [Angular](https://angular.io/) app that is using [ngx-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap), I would like to add a collapse icon which reflects the status of the [accordion](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/accordion) (collapsed/expanded) like the following:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please put a sample of the code you are currently working with?

Comment: exactly the same code as the main example of ngx-bootstrap Accordion: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/accordion#examples

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution that worked for me

```html
<accordion-group [isOpen]="false" #myGroup>
  <button class="btn btn-light float-right">
    {{ myGroup?.isOpen ? 'Opened' : 'Closed' }}
    <i class="fas" [ngClass]="{'fa-caret-down': myGroup?.isOpen, 'fa-caret-up': !myGroup?.isOpen}"></i>
  </button>
</accordion-group>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can basically do this in css :

```
.accordion-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]:before {
    content: "\f107";
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
}

.accordion-toggle[aria-expanded="false"]:before {
    content: '\f106';
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
}
```

*Just have to style the before selector with the font familly of your favorite icon...*

Comment: Can you give me a concrete example of the icons? Currently I'm using https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46297828/bootstrap-4-change-caret-on-clicking-dropdown

Comment: Updated, just have to include you font awesome css

Comment: @candybeer I've included font awesome css but it doesn't work: I only see an empty rectangle (while other font-awesome icons still works).

Answer (score 3):

Following answer works with `ngx-bootstrap@5.x.x`. Also solves the problem for people wanting to use something different than FontAwesome:

```html
<!-- Please note that the #accordionGroupRef is scoped! -->
<accordion-group
    *ngFor="let number of [1,2,3,4];"
    [isOpen]="false"
    #accordionGroupRef
>

    <!-- Header -->
    <h5 class="m-0" accordion-heading>
        {{ accordionGroupRef.isOpen ? "OPEN" : "CLOSED"}}
        I am accordion {{number}}
        <span class="float-right"> I float all the way on the right!</span>
    </h5>    

    <!-- Content -->
    Accordion content
</accordion-group>
```

Comment: how did you scope that  #accordionGroupRef?

Comment: Whenever you use `<ng-template>` or a structural directive like `*ngIf` or `*ngFor `it creates a new template scope and template reference variables: http://www.writesomecode.in/Angular/Using-Template-Reference-Variables-In-Angular7

Comment: Also works on version 4 of ngx-bootstrap ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `accordion-group` input `isOpen`.

HTML

```
<accordion-group [isOpen]="isContentOpen">
  <button class="btn btn-light float-right">
    <i *ngIf="isContentOpen" class="fas fa-caret-up">Open</i>
    <i *ngIf="!isContentOpen" class="fas fa-caret-down">Close</i>
  </button>
</accordion-group>
```

TS

```
isContentOpen: boolean = false;
```

I recommend installing https://fontawesome.com/

Comment: I wish it were this simple, but 1) the button his hidden while the accordion-group is closed, and 2) the variable does not get updated when the button is pressed or when the panel is toggled by other means (like clicking on the heading itself), so the button glyph won't stay in sync.

Comment: Although if you use the `accordion-heading` directive showcased here https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/accordion (e.g. `<button ... accordion-heading>`) all that's needed beyond that is to update the variable during `<accordion-group (isOpenChange)="isContentOpen = !isContentOpen">`.