# How do I toggle the caret back and forth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created two collapses using Bootstrap and added caret to indicate the position of the div. Now the issue seems to be I'm not able to trigger caret down and back to normal.

Can anyone help?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#VehicleGeneralSettings" class="drop-down-caret btn-blank veh-btn-color mt-2"><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-caret-text"></i> Vehicle General Settings</button>
<div class="collapse show mb-4 mt-4" id="VehicleGeneralSettings">
  Hello World
</div>


<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#VehicleListing" class="drop-down-caret btn-blank veh-btn-color mb-2"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-caret-text"></i> Vehicle Data Set</button>
<div class="collapse vehicle-details-box mb-4" id="VehicleListing">
  Hello World 2
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Bill, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please tell what code you have tried to get this to work? [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) you can see an example of an accordion which seems to function almost exactly the same you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You need to rotate the caret on collapse either by toggling the `fa-rotate-180` class on the font-awesome `<i>` element or by doing it via CSS using `transform: rotate(180deg)`. See this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46297828/bootstrap-4-change-caret-on-clicking-dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using css `::before` pseudo-element

`\f0d7` is a [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/) unicode for down caret.

```css
.drop-down-caret::before {
  content: '\f0d7';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}

.drop-down-caret.collapsed::before {
  content: '\f0da';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#VehicleGeneralSettings" class="drop-down-caret btn-blank veh-btn-color mt-2">
Vehicle General Settings
</button>
<div class="collapse show mb-4 mt-4" id="VehicleGeneralSettings">
  Hello World
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bit of pure css trick that will work for you.
Notice the added style in below code.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
[data-toggle="collapse"] i {
  transform: rotate(90deg) ;
  }   
[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed i {
  transform: rotate(0deg) ;
}
</style>

<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#VehicleGeneralSettings" class="drop-down-caret btn-blank veh-btn-color mt-2"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-caret-text"></i> Vehicle General Settings</button>
<div class="collapse show mb-4 mt-4" id="VehicleGeneralSettings">
  Hello World
</div>
```